# Updating nested form while changing tabs (Jquery-ui tabs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a big nested form that I divided into some tabs.

I want to call an updating action from controller each time I change tabs (Jquery-ui tabs), but I don't know how to call an ajax from the tabs jquery. How can i do it?

My code:

application.js

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            url: "stories/update_tabs",
            type: "PUT",
            success: function() {
                $("#message").html = "Data saved.";
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                console.log(anchor);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

controller

```
def update_tabs
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.save
        format.html
      else
        format.html
      end
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :stories do
    put 'update_tabs', on: :collection
end
```

view

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Chapters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Special Attributes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Graph</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :chapters do |builder| %>
          <%= render "chapters_fields", f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to_add_fields "Add chapters", f, :chapters, "chapters" %>
        </p>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :special_attributes do |builder| %>
          <%= render "special_attributes_fields", f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Special Attributes", f, :special_attributes, "special_attributes" %>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |builder| %>
          <%= render "items_fields", f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to_add_fields "Add items", f, :items, "items" %>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-4">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.input :title %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.input :resume, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, style: 'width: 100%' } %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.input :prelude, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, style: 'width: 100%' } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-5">
        <%= render "graph" %>
      </div>
    </div><br/>
```

I just want to do an update, and show a message on some tag with id=message

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

I tried something like this

application.js

```
   $("#tabs").tabs({
        active: function(event,ui) {
            ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'PUT';
            ui.ajaxSettings.url += 'stories/update_tabs';
            //ui.ajaxSettings.format = {format:'html'};
            ui.jqXHR.success(function(){
                $('#message').html = "Data saved";
                console.log("saving");
            });
            ui.jqXHR.error(function(){
                $('#message').html = "Data is not being updated.";
                console.log("not saving");
            })
        }
    });
```

but ajaxSettings.type is undefined on the console, as ajaxSettings.url or other attributes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do in my own project to do actions when changing tabs:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        //Things to do in tabs when activated

        //For instance, this code is applied when activating "tabs-2"   
        if (ui.newPanel.attr("id") == "tabs-2"){
            console.log("You are now in tabs-2")
        }
    }
})
```

If you need to change the ajax url for each tab dynamically, this is how I do that:

```
    $("#tabs ul li a").each(function(index){
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                url = "pageone.php?q="+somedata
                break
            case 1:
                url = "pagetwo.php?q="+somedata
                break
            case 2:
                url = "pagethree.php?q="+somedata
                break
            case 3:
                url = "pagefour.php?q="+somedata
                break
        }        
        $(this).attr('href',url)
    })
```

Edit: Url method is deprecated in Jquery UI 1.10, as stated [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-url-method-and-use-of-title-attribute-use-aria-controls-attribute).

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but jquery tabs by default reloads ajax tabs each time a tab is activated.

Comment: On chapters tab I need data from what user input in Items tab for example, (I will put a select tag in chapter that uses data from items), so, if the user changes form when he is on Items tab, when he returns to chapters tab, I want that information updated. I tried to do an auto-save function with ajax, but i'm using nested forms, and when I add new fields, it doesn't work too well, so i'm trying this aproach (updating on each tab change)

Comment: @HugoTamaki, what UI version are you using? Up to 1.9.x, 'ajaxOptions' is the correct syntax, but from 1.10 it is deprecated in favor of 'ajaxSettings'. Maybe this is why you get undefined in console?

Comment: I'm using jquery-ui 1.10. I called a $.ajax on an "activate" event, and it's updating! I have one more question: Is there a way to re-render just one tab? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do `$("#tabs").tabs('load',x)` where x is the index of the tab you want to reload :)

Comment: I did it! I'm using sigma js plugin to make a graph in one of the tabs, what i actually did was: "if you choose any tab, erase all the content of sigma's div, if you choose the sigma's tab, then draw it from zero". Each time the user modifies the other tabs, the graph changes, that was the way i found to update it. Is it the correct way? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with sigma.js, but your approach sounds just fine to me :)